# Excel - Selecting date from dropdown results in odd date being returned

Tags: excel

I have a drop down list which is populated with a range of dates, configured like so:

[image: Drop down configuration]

The cell G4 is used as an output cell so i can see that the correct date is being selected (it'll be used in a calculation but that's irrelevant at this point!). The problem i am having is that when i select for example, 01/01/2012 from the dropdown box, in the output cell i see 01/01/1900.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the output is not the value in the dropdown but rather the position in the list. format G4 as a number and then use that in an offset to look up the actual date in A1:A15

```
=offset(A1,G4-1,0)
```

G4 will be 1 based, but offset needs to be 0 based, hence the -1.